# PayPal .NET SDK safe to use in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: .net, paypal, xamarin.forms

On the pay-pal site I 've found this: [PayPal Mobile SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/)

There is a SDK for `Android/iOS`.

And there also is the [PayPal-NET-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK).

Can I use this for my `Xamarin.Forms` app ? - cause I ask myself if there are any differences between the `"mobile" SDK`and the `.NET SKD`. For example any conditions I need to meet, when on mobile ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'safe' to use.
Both seem to come from verified PayPal accounts, so in that kind of terms it is certainly safe to use.

The SDKs you are referring to probably both offer you the same kind of functionalities. However the 'mobile' SDKs they are referring to seem to be the native SDKs to be used with Objective-C/Swift for iOS and Java for Android.

Because you want to work with Xamarin - which is .NET - you probably want to go for the .NET SDK. This is probably the easiest to implement with the rest of your shared .NET code.

If you really want to you could use the 'mobile' SDKs but you would have to create your own bindings etc. which is some advanced stuff in Xamarin. And in the end you will probably end up with the same functionality.

Note that the .NET SDK lists '.NET 4.0 or later' as prerequisite, so it might not be compatible with PCLs. Please have a look at the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/) on 'Sharing code options' as to what a PCL is exactly.

Comment: thanks for ur answer ! I'm a bit confused what u mean by "might not be compatible with PCLs"... ? What is the problem there ? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/ there it says it includes .NET 4 / 4.5 ?!

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to the Xamarin documentation as to 'code sharing options'. Also in there is described what a PCL is. In short; a PCL is a true cross-platform DLL. But, to be cross-platform is only supports a subset of the .NET framework depending on what target platforms you select. So not all methods are available. Because of that, NuGet packages that you want to add to a PCL, need to be compatible with that subset of the .NET framework. This is known as a PCL profile. If the answer helped you and is the right one according to you, please mark is as an aswer :)

Comment: thanks for your effort mate ! how can I find out if the .NET SDK provides such a pcl profile ?

Comment: The easiest way is to just try and install the NuGet package. If it fails it will tell you that it cannot install because the targeted platform isn't supported :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this NuGet package a friend created (they are the bindings of this SDK's):

https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/PayPal.Forms